# Using a class outside of class header

Tags: c++, class

I've been looking at examples for a component-based system and in some of the examples, I noticed the usage of class names outside of other classes like in the example below. What is the purpose/function of creating `class Foo;` and `class Bar;` and what is this called?

```
#pragma once

#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

class Foo; // ???
class Bar; // ???

class Example
{
public:
    Example() :
        m_pExample(0) {}
    virtual ~Example() {}

    void something(const Foo& foo, const Bar& bar);

private:
    Example* m_pExample;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a forward declaration and declares class name as a valid but leaves out the definition. This mean that you can use the name as a type before the definition is encountered.

[What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration)

Comment: Thx. Now that I know, I will look more into it.

Comment: I linked in another answer that delves into it

Comment: Nothing to do with run-time.

Comment: @NeilKirk, you are correct, it is very over simplistic answer. I will expand on that

Answer (score 1):

Those are called forward declaration

This help the compiler know that the type exists and it knows nothing about its size, members, and methods.

Therefore its a an incomplete type too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you already have `#include "foo.h"` and `#include "bar.h"` (assuming the class definition of each class is already in its related .h file), I don't see why you should have the two `class Foo;` and `class Bar;` statement.

Usually the reason of putting the `class Foo;` and `class Bar;` is that ***you*** are going to provide the definition of the two classes yourself.

Example:

```
#pragma once

class Foo; 
class Bar; 

class Example
{
public:
    Example() :
        m_pExample(0) {}
    virtual ~Example() {}

    void something(const Foo& foo, const Bar& bar);

private:
    Example* m_pExample;
};

class Foo
{
    // Definition of Foo class goes here...
    ;
};

class Bar
{
    // Definition of Bar class goes here...
    ;
};
```